MyPy reporting problem: NamedTuple type as an attribute is not supported
I have the following class, and MyPy is reporting the problem NamedTuple type as an attribute is not supported for the self.Data attribute.
from collections import namedtuple
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class Record(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, recordname: str, fields: list, records=None):
        if records is None:
            records = []
        self.fields = fields
        defaults = [""] * len(fields)
        self.Data = namedtuple(recordname, self.fields, defaults=defaults)
        self._records = [self.Data(**record) for record in records]
        self.valid_fieldnames = set(self.fields)

        self.lookup_tables: dict = {}

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self._records[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
        self._records[idx] = self.Data(**val)

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        del self._records[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._records)

    def insert(self, idx, val):
        a = self._records[:idx]
        b = self._records[idx:]
        if isinstance(val, self.Data):
            self._records = a + [val] + b
        else:
            self._records = a + [self.Data(**val)] + b

I don't understand what the issue is that MyPy is reporting on, and haven't had any luck looking online. The code actually runs as expected without any errors; it's only MyPy that reports an issue and I'm just curious to understand what it is.
Some additional info: I am using Python-3.12 in VS Code with the official MyPy Type Checker extension, which is what's reporting the problem.
I tried a few things to see if the error would go away, but none of them worked. For example, I removed MutableSequence as a parent class, I deleted the defaults from the namedtuple constructor, and I removed all the dunder methods, but the error persisted.

IMO, mypy is overly conservative on this point. PyRight accepts it.

This makes a lot of sense if you consider how namedtuple works. It's a code-generator, and it creates a new type.
Therefore, if you use it during the class init like this, you will be generating a new type per-instance, and different instances of Record will have different types for self.Data, even if they have the same typename and fields.
A static type checker such as Mypy can not do anything useful with attribute value types being created dynamically at runtime. Further, the if isinstance(val, self.Data) logic in the insert method is likely to have some unpleasant surprises, because the types associated with different record instances will have separate identities.

It's not clear why the value being this particular subclass to tuple matters. Even with the error, the inferred type of self.Data is just type[tuple[Any, ...]], per the return type of namedtuple.

I mean, https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10954 supports this interpretation, I just think mypy is being overly conservative.

@chepner Mypy says it "is not supported", which is just factual. This is a more relevant GitHub issue. I suppose they could have just ignored the attribute, rather than report a problem, but then the problem in the logic of the insert method wouldn't have been revealed. So probably it's better that Mypy was conservative here.

Yes, but why should mypy care if an attribute has as its value a dynamically created type? The attribute itself has a perfectly valid static type, and the value can't be used for static typing even if it were a concrete type like int.

I don't know how to make the OP code lint clean,
as the whole str --> class aspect is a bit more
dynamic than a static type checker is usually looking for.
But this will get it a little closer to passing $ mypy --strict *.py.
from typing import Any


class Record(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(
        self,
        recordname: str,
        fields: list[str],
        records: list[namedtuple] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        ...
        self.lookup_tables: dict[str, str] = {}

Perhaps you have a handful of namedtypes in mind,
which can be imported into this module.
Then create a class which admits any of those types,
and use assert isinstance() or a
TypeVar
to tell mypy what we have.
Let us know
what final solution you settle upon.

are you sure list[namedtuple] is a valid type annotation? namedtuple is not a type

@juanpa.arrivillaga, yeah, I agree, not a type. Was trying to get mypy "closer" -- haven't quite arrived, yet.

typing.NamedTuple is the typing friendly version, but to use it effectively here would require types defined upfront in module-level code. I'm not sure from the O.P. whether that's an option or not (maybe it is, if the possible values of recordname and fields are known in advance).

Thank you. For now I'm leaving it as is since the code runs, but I will revisit this later and update when I settle on something. I'll start with what you suggested and move from there.
